# How to reduce memory use with PhotoKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit

I am using `PhotoKit` to fetch photos from system album and put them in an `UICollectionView`.

1. For the `UICollectionViewCell`, I set it like this:

   ```
   cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   ```
2. When initialing my `UICollectionView`, I fetch the photo `PHAsset` from `collection`: `Camera Roll` only:

   ```
   PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
   [fetchResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *collection, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       NSLog(@"ALBUM NAME: %@", collection.localizedTitle);
       if ([collection.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"Camera Roll"]) {
           _fetchedPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
           _pickedStatuses = @[].mutableCopy;            

           NSMutableArray *assets = @[].mutableCopy;

           _manager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
           _options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
           _options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
           _options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;

           CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
           CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(layout.itemSize.width*scale, layout.itemSize.height*scale);

           //I'm not sure if this api should be called here
           [_manager startCachingImagesForAssets:assets targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:_options];
       }
   }];
   ```
3. Then I request the `UIImage` from `PHFetchResult` from above like this:

   ```
   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       MYCell *cell = (MYCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
       CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(_layout.itemSize.width*scale, _layout.itemSize.height*scale);

       PHAsset *asset = _fetchedPhotos[indexPath.item];
       [_manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:_options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
            cell.imageView.image = result;
       }];

       return cell;
   }
   ```

But when I run it and scroll the `UICollectionView` fast enough, I found the memory use becomes steep like this:

[image: memory use]

How can I reduce it in case it would crash when memory is not enough?

Comment: I would expect this sort of pattern, as before PhotoKit can create the thumbnail it has to load the entire image into memory. Also, are you testing on devices or in the simulator? The memory behavior will be quite different between the two, so always test on device to get a realistic picture of your apps performance.

Comment: I am always testing it on device which is my iPhone 6 Plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have done now is

1. Reduce the target size of fetched `PHAsset` objects;
2. Try to adopt caching. My code is like below:

   ```
   CGFloat scale = 1.5; //or an even smaller one
   if (!_manager) {
       _manager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
   }
   if (!_options) {
       _options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
   }
   _options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
   _options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;

   NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, _fetchedPhotos.count);
   NSIndexSet *set = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
   NSArray *assets = [_fetchedPhotos objectsAtIndexes:set];

   CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(_layout.itemSize.width*scale, _layout.itemSize.height*scale);

   [_manager startCachingImagesForAssets:assets targetSize:targetSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:_options];
   ```

Now even I scroll the `UICollectionView` fast enough, the top memory would be less than `50 MB`, and thanks to `Caching` (I guess it is working based on my code) it doesn't fluctuate that much, memory use is like this:

[image: better memory use]

**UPDATE**
According to another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931023/how-to-get-fullsize-image-ios8-photokit), it is recommended not to specify `PHImageRequestOptions` object. Instead, you could leave it to iOS to decide what is the best for you to present the photos with best quality and least time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the answer i have mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533934/how-to-use-phcachingimagemanager/31218785#31218785). Not only would this help you with caching, but the Photos Framework example by apple would help you get through any problems whatsoever.